# how do i perform a lookup on powerapps?

Tags: powerapps

please, i am new on powerapps.
I have a table (avastaff)with two columns, staffno and staffname.i have also done a form with my datacards being StaffNumber_DataCard3 and StaffName_DataCard2.i want be able to get staffname when the staffno is selected.my function is as below, yet im still getting an error. LookUp(avastaff, StaffNumber = StaffNumber_DataCard3.Text).StaffName

this is what i tried, i got an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtGJF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming StaffNumber is a number and not text - you will need to use Value(...) to convert it. Try:

```
LookUp(avastaff, StaffNumber = Value( StaffNumber_DataCard3.Text) ).StaffName
```